# How to retrieve data from sqlite manager

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, ios6

I created database and also created table in that by using sqlite manager(mozilla).Now i want to retrieve that data into my iOS application.How can i do with programatically. Can you please any one help me how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Follow the below tutorials http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm                                          http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

import:

```
#import "sqlite3.h"
```

CHECK IF DB EXISTS:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *databasePath;
sqlite3 *DB;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"YourDbName.sqlite"]]; //put your db name here

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &DB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS YourTable (Value INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, column TEXT)";


        if (sqlite3_exec(DB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {

        }

        sqlite3_close(DB);

    }
}
```

Get DB Values:

```
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;


        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &DB) == SQLITE_OK)  //News is a sqlite variable initialized like this: sqlite3* News;
        {
            NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM YourDBName"];

            const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSString* example; //example variable to assign data from db

                    example = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]; //change the 0 to 1,2,3.... for every column of your db

                }


                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
            sqlite3_close(DB);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @Singo.It is necessary to set the path of the database file?

Comment: edited my code, you first need to check if the db exists then you can access it, you just need to edit the DB name and the query that creates the DB if it doesn't exists with what you need (table name and column names)

Comment: You need to make it clear that the seeded database file must be copied from the app bundle to the app document directory before it can be used.  Alternatively the tables can be created programmatically and no copying is required.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot that because I only used this method to create the DB so I didn't had to copy it from the bundle to the app document directory

Comment: if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(News, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){} condition is not working. its says that "no such table :tablename"when i used (sqlite3_errmsg(DB)) in else condition.Can you help me pls

Comment: The path is correct and i had database file and had correct table in that.but still it's showing error like that.

Comment: in this statement "(sqlite3_prepare_v2(News, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){}" 

       News is a sqlite variable initialized like this: sqlite3* News ,you probably haven't changed the name of that variable with the one you created

Comment: Sorry for wrong comment i given DB only instead of News. It's not Working

Comment: what is your sqlite3 variable named?

Comment: I've edited the code above with your variable name, added the 2 missing variable and added the import, copy the code and try, if it doesn't work i think that the problem is on your sql_stmt

Comment: Still am not getting it how can i solve that "sql_stmt" problem.

Comment: It depends on the query you need to execute, take a look at this tutorial in order to clarify how sqlite works, http://hubpages.com/hub/Tutorial-on-Creating-an-IOS-5-SQLite-Database-Application-IOS-5-SQLite

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve that data into your iOS application.follow following steps
lets consider your SQlite DB have name YourDB which have table information and columns Name, Place and City and DatabasePath is your path where you store your SQlite DB

```
 const char *dbpath = [DatabasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &YourDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
 NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"SELECT Place, City FROM students WHERE Name=Bob"];
 const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(YourDB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
           NSString *Place = [[NSString alloc]
                                      initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                         statement, 0)];

            NSString *City = [[NSString alloc]
                                    initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                                    sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
   }
       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(YourDB);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Put that "sqlite" file in App's bundle and then you can use that file.